# Versioning aws policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Currently I log into IAM and edit policies by hand for my S3 bucket. When I change something in the editor, I have no idea what the policy was before unless I exit the editor by canceling and then go back and view it. So there's no way to tell exactly what I've changed. So editing is kind of painful, especially considering that I sometimes find myself changing something and then testing the change, with no trivial way to roll back to where I started.

Another problem created by the lack of version control is there's no log of why or when a particular permission was modified. For example, I would really like to know that the reason we need the ListBucket permission on our bucket is because that was required to get file uploads to work. You know, the kind of thing you might put in a git commit message.

Now that you understand and care deeply about my motivations, I would like to know how best to get my policies into git. To the extent possible, I'd like the only way to change the permissions to be through code that is written by me, with the presumption being that any time you make a change, you commit to the repository. This is not perfect security of course, but it does provide an accounting of what changed when, and gives us a single place where we make changes.

Here's my proposal:

- Create an IAM user called policy_editor
- Revoke policy editing privileges from all users
- Give policy_editor policy editing privileges
- Do not give policy_editor a password (thus have to use api credentials to change policies)

My questions are:

1. Is this possible? (Ideally even the root user wouldn't have permission to edit policies, so that wouldn't happen by accident)
2. Is this a good idea?
3. Is there a better solution?
4. Is there a tool that does this already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, the API is flexible enough to do that. Writing automation around IAM pays off in spades.

By "root user", do you mean the AWS access keys directly on the account? Step 1 is to delete those creds (directly on the account) and only use IAM users for everything.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/IAMBestPractices.html

> Is this a good idea?

Yes, automation is good.

> Is there a better solution?

Well, here are some related ideas:

- Use CloudTrail to log all IAM changes.
- If you disable your IAM-changing privs, create a second user (with MFA enabled) for emergencies.
- For some "dangerous" commands, use automation instead. (i.e. give them a web form where they can delete a bucket, but your code verifies it's OK to delete beforehand.)
- Avoid adding privs directly to people. Always use groups to organize permissions. Don't be afraid to spend some time figuring out what logical permission groups would be. For example, you could have a "debugging production" group.
- Don't get too fine-grained (at least not at first). There is a trade-off between security and bureaucracy here. If people have to ping you for every little permission, they will start requesting privs "just in case".
- Use the conditionals: You can say "you can delete any bucket that doesn't have 'production' in the name". Or "You can terminate instances, but it requires MFA".
- Review your policies regularly. People move around between teams, so people often end up with permissions they don't need. If your groups are well-named, you can make the managers review the permissions needed for their underlings.

> Is there a tool that does this already?

Not that I know of. It's pretty easy via API calls, so someone is going to write it.

(This guy started a project: https://github.com/percolate/iamer )

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'm going to look into CloudTrail, if that provides the history I'm looking for, I might skip the automation for. Completely agree on the other points. As an aside, one thing that bugs me about writing code to do this is that ideally I'd like to have to type username/password for that code to work, but you can only use the token/secret combo to act as an IAM user programatically. Not a big deal, just a little annoying to have to figure out how best to handle that.